# In tkinter, how can I use a function in class A to populate a widget in class B?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter

Primary relevant code is in **class EntryForm** (around line 190) and **class BookmarkAccess** (around line 246)

I am sharing the **global user_id** as a means of querying specific rows of data from the database, after the login is completed.

My current workaround is to use a button on the final page, to populate the listbox (self.title.select) with the queries using the user_id generated post-launch.

I have attempted the following to no avail: inherit BookmarkAccess in EntryForm and pass the widget creation in a button command here. Also tried to parse a complete query on app launch with no user_id restriction and then populate listbox with only relevant user_id, which I also could not get working.

What I would like to do is on some prior screen (such as, immediately upon login and passing updated global user_id), populate the final listbox (self.title_select) so when I access that page the listbox is already full of the intended query rows.

Any assistance or guidance would be much appreicated.

```
import sqlite3 as sql
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

BASE_FONT = ("Bookman Old Style", 10)

user_id = None


class Database:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.connection = sql.connect("testing.db")
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

        try:
            self.cursor.execute(
                """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users
                (username TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
                password TEXT NOT NULL)
                ;"""
            )
            self.connection.commit()
        except sql.OperationalError:
            pass

        try:
            self.cursor.execute(
                """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bookmarks
                (OwnerID INTEGER NOT NULL,
                Title TEXT NOT NULL,
                Link TEXT NOT NULL)
                ;"""
            )
            self.connection.commit()
        except sql.OperationalError:
            pass

    def add_account(self, username, password):
        self.cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO users VALUES (?,?)""", (username, password))
        self.connection.commit()

    def login_func(self, username, password):
        self.cursor.execute("SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = (?)", (username,))
        result = str(self.cursor.fetchone()).strip("'(),")
        print(result)
        if result == password:
            print("true")
            return True
        else:
            print("false")
            return False

    def get_user_id(self, username):
        self.cursor.execute("SELECT rowid FROM users WHERE username = (?)", (username,))
        cleaned_id = str(self.cursor.fetchone()).strip(" ( , ) ")
        return int(cleaned_id)

    def commit_bookmark(self, active_id, title, link):
        if len(title) and len(link) != 0:
            self.cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO bookmarks (OwnerID,Title,Link) 
            VALUES (?,?,?)""", (active_id, title, link,))
            self.connection.commit()
        else:
            print("nothing to bookmark")

    def title_populate(self, active_id):
        self.cursor.execute("SELECT Title FROM bookmarks WHERE OwnerID = (?)", (active_id,))
        return self.cursor.fetchall()

    def bookmarks_by_title(self, param, active_id):
        self.cursor.execute("SELECT Title FROM bookmarks WHERE Title LIKE (?) AND OwnerID=(?)",
                            ('%' + param + '%', active_id,))
        return self.cursor.fetchall()


db = Database()


# complete
class LoginInterface(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        button_styling = ttk.Style()
        button_styling.configure("my.TButton", font=BASE_FONT)

        label_styling = ttk.Style()
        label_styling.configure("my.TLabel", font=BASE_FONT)

        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Login Screen")

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (Login,
                  CreateNew,
                  EntryForm,
                  BookmarkAccess):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(Login)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


# complete
class Login(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.label1 = ttk.Label(self, text="Username: ", style="my.TLabel")
        self.label1.grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.username = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.username.grid(row=1, column=2)

        self.label2 = ttk.Label(self, text="Password: ", style="my.TLabel")
        self.label2.grid(row=2, column=1, pady=10)

        self.password = ttk.Entry(self, show="*")
        self.password.grid(row=2, column=2, pady=10)

        def login_call(event):
            if db.login_func(self.username.get(), self.password.get()) is False:
                print("failed validation")
            else:
                print("validation passed")
                global user_id
                user_id = db.get_user_id(self.username.get())
                controller.show_frame(EntryForm)

        self.login = ttk.Button(
            self, text="Login", style="my.TButton", command=lambda: login_call(Login))
        self.login.grid(row=3, column=2)

        self.create_new = ttk.Button(
            self,
            text="Create New Account",
            style="my.TButton",
            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(CreateNew),
        )
        self.create_new.grid(row=4, column=2, pady=10)


# complete
class CreateNew(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.label1 = ttk.Label(self, text="Set Username:", style="my.TLabel")
        self.label1.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.username = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.username.grid(row=1, column=2)

        self.label2 = ttk.Label(self, text="Set Password:", style="my.TLabel")
        self.label2.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.password = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.password.grid(row=2, column=2)

        self.create_button = ttk.Button(
            self,
            text="Complete New Account",
            style="my.TButton",
            command=lambda: db.add_account(self.username.get(), self.password.get()),
        )
        self.create_button.grid(row=3, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.home = ttk.Button(
            self,
            text="Go to Login",
            style="my.TButton",
            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Login),
        )
        self.home.grid(row=5, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)


# functional
class EntryForm(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        # FIXME
        def view_bookmarks(event):
            print(user_id)
            # BookmarkAccess.title_query = db.title_populate(user_id)
            # BookmarkAccess.title_choices = tk.StringVar(value=BookmarkAccess.title_query)
            # BookmarkAccess.title_select = tk.Listbox(self, listvariable=BookmarkAccess.title_choices)
            # BookmarkAccess.title_select.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=5, pady=10)
            controller.show_frame(BookmarkAccess)

        def add_bookmark(event):
            print(user_id)
            db.commit_bookmark(user_id, self.title.get(), self.link.get(), )
            self.title.delete(0, tk.END)
            self.link.delete(0, tk.END)

        self.title_label = ttk.Label(self, text="Title: ")
        self.title_label.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.link_label = ttk.Label(self, text="Link: ")
        self.link_label.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.title = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.title.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=10)

        self.link = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.link.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=10)

        self.view_bookmarks = ttk.Button(
            self,
            text="View Bookmarks",
            style="my.TButton",
            command=lambda: view_bookmarks(Login),
        )
        self.view_bookmarks.grid(row=5, column=1)

        self.commit_new_bookmark = ttk.Button(
            self,
            text="Add Bookmark",
            style="my.TButton",
            command=lambda: add_bookmark(Login),
        )
        self.commit_new_bookmark.grid(row=2, column=1)


# functional
class BookmarkAccess(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.title_label = ttk.Label(self, text="Filter by Title: ")
        self.title_label.grid(row=0, column=0)

        # title filter: entry box
        self.title_filter = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.title_filter.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=10)

        # FIXME
        self.title_select = tk.Listbox(self)
        self.title_select.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=5, pady=10)

        # title filter
        def title_filtering(event):
            self.title_select.destroy()
            self.title_query = db.bookmarks_by_title(self.title_filter.get(), user_id)
            self.title_choices = tk.StringVar(value=self.title_query)
            self.title_select = tk.Listbox(self, listvariable=self.title_choices)
            self.title_select.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=5, pady=10)

        self.title_filter.bind('<Return>', title_filtering)

        self.title_button = ttk.Button(self, style='my.TButton', text="Filter Title",
                                       command=lambda: title_filtering(Login))
        self.title_button.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=5, pady=10)


app = LoginInterface()
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest to notify raised frame using tkinter virtual event, so that the frame can perform some action upon receiving that virtual event:

```py
class LoginInterface(tk.Tk):
    ...

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()
        frame.event_generate('<<Raised>>') # notify frame
```

Then modify `BookmarkAccess` to populate the listbox upon receiving the virtual event:

```py
class BookmarkAccess(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.title_label = ttk.Label(self, text="Filter by Title: ")
        self.title_label.grid(row=0, column=0)

        # title filter: entry box
        self.title_filter = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.title_filter.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=10)

        self.title_choices = tk.StringVar()
        self.title_select = tk.Listbox(self, listvariable=self.title_choices)
        self.title_select.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=5, pady=10)

        self.title_filter.bind('<Return>', self.title_filtering)

        self.title_button = ttk.Button(self, style='my.TButton', text="Filter Title",
                                       command=self.title_filtering)
        self.title_button.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=5, pady=10)

        self.bind('<<Raised>>', self.title_filtering) # respond virtual event

    # title filter
    def title_filtering(self, event=None):
        self.title_query = db.bookmarks_by_title(self.title_filter.get(), user_id)
        self.title_choices.set([x[0] for x in self.title_query])
```

Note that I have changed nested function `title_filtering()` to class method in order to be used in different situations. Also change to update the list box instead of destroy it and recreate new list box.

Comment: Thank you! This is a great solution. Do you happen to have any idea as to why a bookmark with a two-word title will populate the listbox contained inside {curly brackets} vs a single-word title having no brackets?

Comment: It is added by `tk` lib when converting a list of tuples with spaces inside string in the tupe.  To fix it, change `self.title_choices.set(self.title_query)` to `self.title_choices.set([x[0] for x in self.title_query])`.  Answer is updated.

Comment: As soon as I asked I was able to answer my own question. The solution for anyone who might stumble upon this issue can be found here (I am using the 2nd example structure): https://www.skotechlearn.com/2021/03/add-itmes-in-combobox-tkinter-python.html

Comment: the curly bracket solution you gave is much cleaner than the one I was trying, which carried the side effect of repopulating the value list multiple times. thanks again